# c# Deploy package using SCCM SDK

Tags: c#, sccm

I am using the SCCM SDK and creating a deploy using the C# code below:

```
public string DeployPrograma(WqlConnectionManager connection, string collectionID, string pacote, string nomePrograma)
        {
            string idDeploy = "";

            const Int32 OVERRIED_SERVICE_WINDOWS = 0x00100020;
            const Int32 ENABLE_PRESENT = 0x01000000;
            const Int32 REMOTE_FLAG = 0x00041040;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Iniciando a criação do Deploy...");

                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                IResultObject novoDeploy = connection.CreateInstance("SMS_Advertisement");

                  novoDeploy["CollectionID"].StringValue = collectionID;
                  novoDeploy["PackageID"].StringValue = pacote;
                  novoDeploy["ProgramName"].StringValue = nomePrograma;
                  novoDeploy["AdvertisementName"].StringValue = "Deploy Teste SDK";
                  novoDeploy["Comment"].StringValue = "Deploy realizado via SDK";
                  novoDeploy["AdvertFlags"].IntegerValue = novoDeploy["AdvertFlags"].IntegerValue | OVERRIED_SERVICE_WINDOWS;
                  novoDeploy["DeviceFlags"].IntegerValue = 0;//novoDeploy["DeviceFlags"].IntegerValue | ENABLE_PRESENT;
                  novoDeploy["RemoteClientFlags"].IntegerValue = 41040;//novoDeploy["RemoteClientFlags"].IntegerValue | REMOTE_FLAG;
                  novoDeploy["AssignedScheduleEnabled"].BooleanValue = true;
                  novoDeploy["SourceSite"].StringValue = "TST";
                  novoDeploy["OfferType"].IntegerValue = 0;
                  novoDeploy["PresentTimeEnabled"].BooleanValue = true;
                  novoDeploy["PresentTime"].DateTimeValue = now;
                  novoDeploy["Priority"].IntegerValue = 1;
                  //novoDeploy["ExpirationTime"].DateTimeValue = now.AddDays(1);
                  //novoDeploy["ExpirationTimeEnabled"].BooleanValue = true;
                  novoDeploy["TimeFlags"].IntegerValue = 8211;//novoDeploy["TimeFlags"].IntegerValue | ENABLE_PRESENT;

                  novoDeploy.Put();

                  Console.WriteLine("Deploy realizado: " + novoDeploy["AdvertisementName"].StringValue);

                  novoDeploy.Get(); 

                  idDeploy = novoDeploy["AdvertisementID"].StringValue;
            }
            catch (SmsException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Falha ao realizar o Deploy: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return idDeploy;
        }
```

Deploy appears in the list of deploy, however, it is not published to the client.

If I do the same process via the SCCM Console, the deployment works.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Thank you

Comment: If you check the assignment list (the dates when it should be deployed) is it empty? Or does it say "as soon as possible" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are missing is the assignment which is at which point in time this should be deployed. It can be added like this:

```
List<IResultObject> collectionSchedule = novoDeploy.GetArrayItems("AssignedSchedule");
IResultObject collectionVariable = connection.CreateEmbeddedObjectInstance("SMS_ST_NonRecurring");
collectionVariable["StartTime"].DateTimeValue = dtpAssignSchedule.Value;
collectionSchedule.Add(collectionVariable);
novoDeploy.SetArrayItems("AssignedSchedule", collectionSchedule);
```

If I understand the WMI Classes correctly you need this because you set AssignedScheduleEnabled to true. Maybe if you set this to false it could also work (by switching to "as soon as possible") but I am not 100% sure about this.

Comment: Hi @Syberdoor, thanks a lot! 
This helped me to correct the schedule problem.
What I don't understand is why my client does not see the deploy via SDK, he only sees the deploy created via the console.

Comment: It's hard to tell, to me the code looks fine, what I would do to debug if the assignment did not help is log into the server via some wmiexplorer and look at SMS_Advertisement and compare the one you created in c# with the manual one. It might be that you need to use different AdvertFlags or RemoteClientFlags (this is really dependent on your sccm environment). If they differ a lot try using the exact number from the wmi and if it works reverse engineer the bit that matters. Only thing to keep in mind is that AssignedScheduleEnabled is always false in wmi but needs to be true regardless...

Comment: Thanks again @Syberdoor!
I noticed that when I create the deploy via sdk, the collection is assigned to it, but when I go to the collection, the deployment does not appear for it. My version of sccm is evalution, does that cause the problem?

Comment: I would not think so (would be a very strange limitation) my best bet other than that you simply put a wrong CollectionID which I hope you checked, is that maybe it is a problem with using a not unique name for AdvertisementName. I assumed it does not matter as the Deployment is unique by it's ID but maybe it does. Maybe some old wrongly created deployment is floating around under that name and it breaks something but in general I find it strange that it does not work for you as I use very similar code to create deployments in my environment without trouble

Comment: !  How are you, can you help me, i need to make a simple deploy with an AssignedSchedule, can you show me the exact config in AdvertFlags to make this deploy? Thanks man

Comment: AdvertFlags contain a lot of different options (see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/reference/core/servers/configure/sms_advertisement-server-wmi-class) so I personally always did it like this: Create the Deplyoment manually in the console, got to the SMS_Advertisement class in your servers wmi (root\sms\site_<sitecode>) and just note down the value of the Flags you use in your environment. Imo a lot easier than building it yourself (although it is perfectly possible with the values on the site I posted)